# Why does uninstalling sendmail install exim, and uninstalling exim installs xmail?

Tags: linux, email, sendmail, mailx

I just set up a VPS with Debian 7 x64, and removed Sendmail along with some other programs. When it removed Sendmail, it also installed Exim. When I removed Exim, it installed xmail.

Is there any reason why it seems to require a mail program?

I used `apt-get remove --purge sendmail* exim*` to remove them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your installed packages depends on installed MTA. This is most likely `cron`. You can view why a package (or meta package) is installed with `aptitude`:

```
aptitude why mail-transport-agent
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be required by bsd-mailx. But why doesn't `apt-get remove --purge xmail` remove xmail and mark bsd-mailx as not needed? Instead it tries to install Sendmail again. Even if I remove bsd-mailx first, removing xmail will result in it installing Sendmail.

Answer (score 2):

There are over 100 packages which depend on or recommend mail-transport-agent. but one of these is real annoying that is the lsb-core package. In most cases when you have a package that depends on mail-transport-agent you really need a mail transport agent, but many packages that depend on lsb-core don't. That is why there is lsb-invalid-mta. This package is designed for the times when you don't need or want a mta but your computer thinks you do.

on the other hand you might have other programs that really need to send mail, in which case you might want to look at nullmailer or similar.